# After redirecting site to HTTPS Google Search Console index status dropping for HTTP but staying at 0 for HTTPS

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect, https, google-index

I moved my HTTP site to HTTPS last month. Earlier I had a search console property for `http://www.example.com`. Now I created a new property for `https://www.example.com` 
(also created property for `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`, just to see what it shows).

But the Google index status is showing 0 for my `https://www.example.com`. Why is that so?  The index for the previous property is still showing (though slowly decreasing). Does Google consider my site as 'not adding any value' since there is already an HTTP version? Should I remove other three properties?

I am working on Magento site. It provides settings to use secure URL and I have done that. In addition I have added redirect to HTTPS in .htaccess file.

My robots.txt file just contains this one line:

```
User-agent: *
```

The number of pages indexed in sitemap is same in HTTPS and HTTP.

**Edit :**

.htaccess file :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.whitesouq.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# All explanations you could find in .htaccess.sample file
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124.40.244.18
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Where have you implemented the non-www to www redirect? (If you are using Magento, then presumably your `.htaccess` file contains much more than what you have posted?)

Comment: @user82217,I have too much code in my .htaccess file, I have edited the question with code I think relevent with redirects. I added the code as per the answer given by user-TopQnA to this question.As newbie, not much aware of what it does. Does that redirect non-www to www?

Comment: "The number of pages indexed in sitemap is same in HTTPS and HTTP." - so GSC is reporting indexed pages for the HTTPS property? Presumably your HTTPS sitemap contains just your HTTPS URLs? Which version of the URL(s) appear in the SERPs? (As Stephen mentioned in comments, the GSC reports are sometimes out of date.) The code example by TopQnA is intended to be _instead of_ your existing redirect(s), not in addition to (in your case that would seem to only add code-bloat, it shouldn't break anything though).

Comment: @user82217 site:example.com return both https and non https pages. So google is indexing my pages,right? my sitemap www.whitesouq.com/sitemap.xml is automatically generated by magento framework.

Comment: Yes, Google is indexing your pages under HTTPS. In fact, you currently appear to have many more HTTPS pages indexed than HTTP pages (129 HTTPS vs 59 HTTP ... 188 total). Using `site:www.example.com inurl:https`.

Comment: @user82217, great to know that, Thanks for you valueable replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done in search console looks fine.

The only thing i would say is when you redirected from http://www to https://www make sure the http to https redirect response is 301.

Also, make sure all other version of URLs (http://, https://, http://www.) redirects to preferred URL (https://www.) and the server response should be 301.

Once this is done, you don't need to anything else and in search console just look at your preferred URL property.

**.htaccess code to directed to: https://www.example.com.au in Magento:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


#RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'd just add that the search console indexing numbers are often unreliable or updated infrequently.  Having multiple versions registered in search console never negatively effects your site.

Comment: @TopqnA ,Thanks for the reply. http:// and http://www gives server response as 301,but https://example.com gives response as 302, is that a problem? (edited the question with .htaccess file)

Comment: I don't suspect example.com (http:// example.com) redirect response 302 as a problem because your original URL was http://www But i would still recommend all other should have 302 response. I have amended the answer and you may like to try above code.

Comment: @TopQnA, I have Edited the .htaccess file with the codes you have given. As a newbie, i am not much aware of what it does, but hopes it works good for me. Will it redirect https non-www to https www? And should I replace %{HTTP_HOST} with example.com?

Comment: Just test other URLs and see the redirect and server response. Make sure you check the outcome.

Comment: Minor point... the `NC` flag should be removed on the two `RewriteCond` directives with a _negated_ CondPattern. Otherwise, it will never match the malformed request it is intended to trap. The first two rule blocks should also be combined into one - they both do the same thing (redirect non-www to www).

Comment: @user82217, I have no idea how it works. It would be of great help if you provide me with the combined code.

Comment: You have to apply changes at only 2 places, .htaccess and admin. How far it worked for you so far? Anything in particular not working for you?

Comment: @TopQnA when I check my site whitesouq.com using redirectcheck.com, everything redirects perfectly. It would be great If you can tell me what are the changes to be applied.

Comment: All looks good, don't bother too much from Webmaster Tools side, just check preferred version and ignore others.